# java- return integer value of average score?

Tags: java, swing, bluej

I am trying to write a program in java that takes 3 students names and scores, then computes an average of their scores. Here is a detailed list of what I am trying to achieve:

- Modify the Student class to have three new instance variables of type int named score1, score2, and score3.
- Modify the Student class to have a method named averageScore that returns an int value that is the average of these three scores.
- Modify method main to input three scores for each of the student objects   you have already created.
- Print each student's name followed by their average score as an integer.

## StudentTester Main class

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class StudentTester {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Student student1 = new Student();
        Student student2 = new Student();
        Student student3 = new Student();
        
        
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        
        //start first student here 
        firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the student's first name.");
        student1.setFirstName(firstName);
        
        lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the student's last name.");
        student1.setLastName(lastName);
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student 1 has name "
                + student1.getFirstName() + ""+ student1.getLastName() + ".");
        
        score1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the student's score.");
        student1.setScore(score1);
            int student1; getScore();
            
        //start second student here
        firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the student's first name.");
        student2.setFirstName(firstName);
        
        lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the student's last name.");
        student2.setLastName(lastName);
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student 2 has name "
                + student2.getFirstName() + "" + student2.getLastName() + ".");
                
        score2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the student's score. ");
        student2.setScore(score2);
 
        //start third student here
        firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the student's first name.");
        student3.setFirstName(firstName);
        
        lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the student's last name.");
        student3.setLastName(lastName);
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student3 has name "
                + student3.getFirstName() + "" + student1.getLastName() + ".");
        
        //average score
                

            }
        }
```

## Student class

```
public class Student {
    
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public int score1;
    public int score2;
    public int score3;
    
    public void setFirstName(String name){
        firstName = name;
    }
    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String name){
        lastName = name;
    }
    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }
    
    public String setScore(){
        int score1 = Integer.parseInt(score1Store);
    }
    
    //method for average score computation
    public void score1 = Integer.parseInt(Score);
    
    public double getAverageScore(){
        return double = ( score1 + score2 + score3)/3.0;
       
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am completely lost, and unsure of how to set up the whole score input and computation.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to add (and call) `setScore1(int)`, `setScore2(int)` and `setScore3(int)` you now have three scores... not one.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't for getting people to do your homework for you. If you're completely lost, you need to go back to base principles and study the underlying syntax.

Comment: @Zaphod42 Rude, I am just asking for some direction.

Comment: @bretth18 Rude? Try reading the stackoverflow rules sometime.

Answer (score 0):

In Student, you should have score1, score2, and score3 as private instance variables at the top and have getters and setters for them just like you did for the firstName and lastName. You could have separate getters and setters for each one, but there are multiple ways to do this.

You can return an int value from the getAverageScore like:

```
public int getAverageScore() {
    float ans = (score1 + score2 + score3)/3.0f;
    return Math.round(ans);
```

I used a float because Math.round with a double will return a long.

In the main method, you could can set the scores with your setScores() method.

```
student1.setScore1(score1);
student1.setScore2(score2);
student1.setScore3(score3);
```

To print the students, you could create a toString method in Student or you get use your getters to print them. The toString method would look like:

```
public String toString() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName + " " + score1 + " " + score2 + " " + score3;
}
```